# Safariにて $(window).on("focus"〜 すると setInterval が 2回実行される

Tags: javascript, safari, es6

es6で書いているので $interval と書いていますが、 setIntervalと同じです。

OS:
OSX El Capitan

ブラウザ:
Safari バージョン 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)
Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

以下のコードで、save();が2回呼ばれてしまいます。
原因を教えていただけますか。

```
var timeout;
$(window).on("focus",() => {
  timeout = $interval(() => {
    console.log("window is active");
    var time = 0;
    time++;
    console.log(time);
    save();
  }, 1000);
}).on("blur",function(){
  $interval.cancel(timeout);
  console.log("window is not active");
});
```

Comment: ところで$intervalはES6ではなくAngularJSの機能では？

Comment: この状態では回答しづらいですが、この`focus`をバインドしている箇所が2回呼ばれていませんか？

Comment: 「1秒に一度save()が呼ばれるはずが1秒に2回呼ばれる」ということでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

試したらjQueryの$(window).on('focus')はSafariだと二回走りました。

windowがactiveになったかどうか判断する方法はブラウザごと違って、jQueryでは内部で吸収して$(window).on('focus')で判定できるようにしてるっぽいですが、たぶんSafariで仕様が変わって二回走るようになっちゃったとかじゃないでしょうか。

jQueryで判定するなら以下のようにinterval動いてるときは実行しないとかするしかないかな。

```
var timeout;
$(window).on("focus",() => {
  if ( timeout ) {
    return;
  }
  timeout = $interval(() => {
    console.log("window is active");
    var time = 0;
    time++;
    console.log(time);
    save();
  }, 1000);
}).on("blur",function(){
  $interval.cancel(timeout);
  timeout = null;
  console.log("window is not active");
});
```

```js
var focusCount = 0;
$(window).on('focus', function(evt){
  console.log(evt);
  $('#output').text(++focusCount);
});
```

```html
<p id="output">0</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```